# Разрешить выбирать ForeignKey с конкретным значением

Tags: python, django, orm

Есть модель `Account`, в которой есть CharField `account_type`.

Как в другой модели сделать поле `ForeignKey(account)` так, чтобы в админке можно было выбрать только те аккаунты, которые имеют `account_type == "user"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае лучше использовать limit_choices_to

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
   account = models.ForeignKey(
       Account,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       limit_choices_to={'account_type': 'user'},
   )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Comment: Если не стоит задача ограничивать значения поля только в админке.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, сложно представить ситуацию, когда нужно ограничить админку, не ограничивая кастомный ModelForm, думаю в 99% случаев limit_choices_to вполне подойдет.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю :)

Comment: А формы в проекте не используются, это бэкенд, построенный целиком на json-запросах, но в данном конкретном случае -- поле предполагается изменять из админки только. :)

Answer (score 0):

В документации [есть ответ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) на это:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "account":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Account.objects.filter(account_type="user")
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```